# extract part of a class from div class with jquery

Tags: jquery

I work with jquery 1.3.2(do not ask me why) I have some pages where each has its identification number put inside body class like this xxx-123, xxx-124 etc. I would like to find and extract (put to variable) a part of a div class(only the number). First I look for class that identifies certain pages "abc" and then I look for class starting with "xxx-"

html

```
<div id="body" class="abc cde fgh xxx-23">text</div>
```

script

```
if ($("#body").hasClass("cde")) {
     var clasa = $('div[class*=xxx-]');
    alert(clasa);
}
```

Testing alert gives me object object message. Can anybody help solving this simple thing? Thank you.

http://jsfiddle.net/q34w9mbj/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the `class` attribute and then extract the class name

```js
if ($("#body").hasClass("cde")) {
  var clasa = $('div[class*=xxx-]').attr('class').match(/\bxxx-.+?\b/);
  alert(clasa);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body" class="abc cde fgh xxx-23">text</div>
```

---

But a more simpler solution will be is to use a data-* attribute

```js
if ($("#body").hasClass("cde")) {
  var xxx = $('div[data-xxx]').attr('data-xxx');
  alert(xxx);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body" data-xxx="23" class="abc cde fgh">text</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. One more question - is the selector $('div[class*=xxx-]') going to look in the actual div #body only? Thank you

Comment: @user1031743 no... in that case change it to `$('#body').attr('class').match(/\bxxx-.+?\b/);`